# Laravel define database in model

Tags: laravel

A chunk of my SQL is held in a different database to the rest of my Laravel installation.

When I use a particular Model, how do I define in that Model, that I'd like to use a particular database and not the one defined in config/database.php?

I am using Laravel 5 so needs to be relevant to that version.

Update: Here is my model;

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

  class Lookup extends Model {
    protected $connection = 'postcodes';
  }
```

Here is part of my `config/database.php`;

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', $_ENV["DB_HOST"]),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', $_ENV["DB_DATABASE"]),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', $_ENV["DB_USERNAME"]),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', $_ENV["DB_PASSWORD"]),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],

    'postcodes' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', $_ENV["DB_HOST"]),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'postcodes'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', $_ENV["DB_USERNAME"]),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', $_ENV["DB_PASSWORD"]),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
```

It's not working - and I can't get Whooops errors to work so all I get is a white screen (but that's a separate issue).

I know my controller code is correct because when I temporarily copy the table in to my main Laravel database, it all works fine. So what's the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the same question on the [Laravel forum](http://laravel.io/forum/03-26-2015-switching-database-connections-does-not-work?page=1#reply-22607) and the posted solution worked for me.

Basically the problem is this line;

```
'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', $_ENV["DB_DATABASE_TWO"]),
```

Or in my code above at the time of writing it was actually;

```
'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'postcodes'),
```

It needs to be;

```
'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE_TWO', $_ENV["DB_DATABASE_TWO"]),
```

And then your `.env` file needs to have `DB_DATABASE_TWO=postcodes` (or whatever the name of your second database is).

Answer (score 0):

You can define `protected $connection = 'yourohterconnection';` in your model, and add another connection to your database config file.

Comment: could you try querying once in a very explicity with `Lookup::on('postcodes')->where... ` and see if it works ? Because the one i told you is the way you assign defined connections to models in laravel, so it should work

Comment: I have moved all my models in to a models folder.... Could that be causing issues?

Comment: Like this do you mean.. `$postcode_lookups['lookups'] = Lookup::on('postcodes')->select('tablename')->distinct()->get();` It didn't work

Comment: What error do you get? As far as I see, you should not use the `select()` statement unless you need specific columns, you can just run `Lookup::on('postcodes')->get()` and see if you can access the right db

Comment: I tried your `Lookup::on('postcodes')->get()`. It does not work at all. I just get a blank screen as the whoops error page is missing. Just a blank white page. Useful, huh!

Comment: That's a very strange issue. A blank page could mean a syntax error, check the web server logs. Secondly, since you use a namespace, you maybe have to call the model accordingly, like `App\Models\Lookup::on('connection')->first()`

Comment: I've already made a namespace for that model. I can connect to the model as implied above when I moved the table to the main database. Is there any other way to force the databases connection to change? This would take about 30 seconds with procedural this is a joke!

Comment: I have found a way of doing it... I might submit this as an answer. If all else fails - you can do `protected $table = 'postcodes.lookups';` in your model and it will use the postcodes database. Not ideal though if you have different usernames and passwords for that database